# how to add a login screen before existing ViewController in Xcode3

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, authentication, uiviewcontroller

I need to add a screen to capture username and password before loading the first view of an app on an iPhone.  The whole app is coded and working except for this (late) addition.  This is my first app in Xcode so I am not very familiar with the system at all.

I have a LoginViewController set up, but don't know how to add it to the front of the app so that it loads first and then loads my RootViewController afterwards (I need the login details before loading the next view).

The header of my appdelegate is presently

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class RootViewController;
@interface Online_HW_DiaryAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {

UIWindow *window;
RootViewController *viewController;

UINavigationController *navigationController;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navigationController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet RootViewController *viewController;

@end
```

but I'm not sure what I need to modify - or indeed what else will need to be modified?  Any advice gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the fastest path is this:  In viewDidAppear of RootViewController, detect the login needed condition and present a new LoginVC modally.

```
// RootViewController.m
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    if (/* user must login */) {
        LoginVC *newVC = [[LoginVC alloc] initWithNibName:.....];
        [self presentModalViewController:newVC animated:YES];
    } else {
        // your old viewwillappear logic
    }
}
```

The LoginVC, upon determining that the user has logged in successfully, can dismiss itself.

```
// LoginVC.m
- (void)loginFinished {

    // after some asynch call that validated the user credentials
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this Dan. I can see the logic here, but I am just getting a blank screen i.e. neither RootViewController or LoginViewController are displaying. There must be more I need to do to get the LoginViewController to be picked up before the existing RootViewController?

Comment: I just checked an old project where this works. Try viewDidAppear with th same idea.

Comment: OK thanks Dan I will pursue this further as it certainly seems to be heading in the right direction!

Comment: Yes the new view is appearing Dan - brilliant.   I need to do some work to get it to detect if the user has already entered their details or not, and to pass the login credentials from the new LoginViewController to the existing RootViewController. Will set to work on this.  Thanks so much for your help - I may come back later!

Comment: Glad to hear.  Feel free to ask follow-up.